# Is there a way to share app configuration between devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, game-center

I've got several games on my phones and tablets that carry over their settings and states between devices (e.g., I leave a game on my phone, and I start it up on my tablet it'll be basically where I left off on the phone).

Or, I can uninstall and reinstall the game and not have lost any progress in the game.

Now, I understand that the state is being saved on a central server by the game publisher, and being downloaded each time the game starts. And I understand that they are linking my profile between them through Game Center.

I'd like to do something similar, but the app I'm working on is not a game. Is there a similar method to know the user of this phone is also the user of this tablet and have the devices pull app settings from my server?

Comment: If I was you, I would give a try do Firebase Realtime Database. It's pretty easy to setup and they Google provides a very detailed documentation. https://firebase.google.com/products/database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most similar API would be [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/cloudkit/). Its essentially free for this sort of thing. Like Game Center its iOS only.

Like kchromik said Firebase would be another option. It works with other platforms as well but doesn't necessarily integrate as well into iOS.